# i want to change nav color when we hit particular section of page how to achieve that

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to add smooth scrolling and also scrollspy to change nav bar color when it hit certain section  while scrolling.Below is my code

```
           <div class="navbar-wrapper">

    <nav class="navbar  navbar-default navbar-fixed-top  navbar-expand-md ">


            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data- 
     toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria- 
   controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle 
           navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggle-icon"></span>


            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " 
           id="navbarSupportedContent" >
              <ul class="  navbar-nav  ml-auto"  style="font-size: 14px;font- 
              weight: 700;" >
                <li  class="nav-item ">
                  <a class="nav-link active "   href="#pagetop">HOME <span 
    class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li   class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link smoothScroll"   href="#whatwedo">WHAT WE 
               DO</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link smoothScroll "   
                      href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
                      </li>
                      <li   class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link "  href="#">LOGIN</a>
                          </li>

                </ul>
                </div>
                </nav>
                </div>
```

i want to change navbar color when it hits

```
      <section id="whatwedo">
```

while scrolling using scrollspy how can i achieve that
i am using following cdn links

```
            <link rel="stylesheet" 
            href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/
             4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >


             <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" > 
                        </script>
                  <script 
         src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/
                   1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
                  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/
                4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script> 

                  <script>
                  $('.navbar-nav .nav-link').click(function(){
                   $('.navbar-nav .nav-link').removeClass('active');
                   $(this).addClass('active');
               })

               </script>
```

Comment: that doesnot solve my problem

Comment: i have managed to apply scrollspy but how do i add class to navbar when home anchor tag doesnot have active class using $('[data-spy="scroll"]').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
          
})